# Calling CloseHandle after calling SetEvent

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I have a thread running in my application. Inside the thread I am waiting on an auto reset event to exit. I want to make sure that i close the handle of the event after i use it. Ihave two options.

1. Calling `CloseHandle` of the event immediately after calling `SetEvent`
2. Calling `CloseHandle` after the line `WaitForSingleObject`

Please suggest me which one is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `CloseHandle` after `SetEvent` doesn't make sense to me. You should (if required) call `CloseHandle` after `WaitForSingleObject` only.

Comment: well then what if WaitForSingleObject has a timeout param and returns (when timed out) even before the other thread calls SetEvent on the handle. If we immediately close the handle after a timed WaitForSingleObject, then later on when the SetEvent is eventually called on the handle, the handle will be invalid (usually begnin situation), or (more insidious but very unlikely to happen) valid but points to some totally different kernel object that reuses the previously closed handle table slot.

Answer (score 6):

Close the handle when all threads have finished using it. After the WaitForSingleObject sounds sensible to me (because if it succeeds, the SetEvent must have completed).

Alternatively - give each thread its own copy of the handle (eg via DuplicateHandle) and have each close their copy when they're finished. That's much harder to get wrong and requires less analysis of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Close event handle when you are sure that event has done its job and is not needed any more. In you case that is after you detect it has been set. So, close event handle after `WaitForSingleObject` unblocks.